# Layer-List items are not showing in ImageView at run time

Tags: android, imageview, android-drawable, layer-list

I'm using a layer-list items to show speech bubble:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:top="55dp"
          android:left="0dp"
          android:height="30dp"
          android:width="60dp"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-45"
            android:pivotX="0%"
            android:pivotY="0%"
            android:toDegrees="0" >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <solid android:color="#6bc160" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

    <item   android:left="0dp"
            android:bottom="0dp"
            android:height="70dp"
            android:width="140dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#6bc160" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And I'm showing this `layer-list drawable` in an `ImageView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_marker"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some text"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some text (text)"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

At compile time it is showing proper drawable in `Android Studio` but when I run the `Application` in mobile, nothing will show in `ImageView`. Can someone help me why is it happening?

Comment: it is showing fine on my device. can you post your whole xml where you are using your imageView ?

Comment: added whole xml code

Comment: On which device/emulator you are testing. Because your code is working fine on my side.

Comment: ohhh, Now only I checked in emulator it's working fine in emulator but in Redmi Note 3 nothing is showing in ImageView.

Comment: well then i thinkyou have to fix your imageview width and height

Comment: I have given custom width and height to ImageView, but now it's showing only normal rectangle from layer-list and not showing rotated rectangle

Comment: why dont you use nine patch drawable as every bubble do?

Comment: Thanks, It will be helpful If u give me a link of best tutorial for nine patch drawable

Comment: @Nadimuddin that's because those attributes only work in API 23 or higher, on lesser api's you will only get a rectangle. As pskink suggested use nine patch drawable or use vector drawable.

Comment: see https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html#&sourceDensity=320&name=example